# Carrierwave gem is not working in Redmine v 2.x Plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I’m using carrier wave gem in a redmine plugin.
But it’s not working as it works in a simple rails app.
For example my uploader class is 
My Uploaders directory contains the file_uploader.rb file which has the following code.

```
    class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
     storage :file

     def store_dir "boxelements/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}/#{mounted_as}"
     end
    end
```

Should I change the code in order to make it work?
Can anyone please tell me why it’s not working as a red mine plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move the “Uploaders” directory into the main app directory of the redmine.